# Accesing array objects dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have below array and trying to access the array objects based on key dynamically but its not giving me the exact object details ,I am getting table1/table2 values dynamically and based on that i am trying to get the table details

```
var arr = [{"table1":{"tablename":"table1","tablecolumns":"no","patternCheckStatus":"true","columns":[{"columnname":"DescriptionGovt","datatype":"AlphaNumeric","patternregex":"(lll);;;"},{"columnname":"GovtGrant","datatype":"Alphabetic","patternregex":"(lkkll)"}]}},{"table2":{"tablename":"table2","tablecolumns":"no","patternCheckStatus":"false","columns":[{"columnname":"DateItem","datatype":"LowerCase","patternregex":"(3rdtable)hhhh"}]}}]

var id = table1;
console.log("obj " + JSON.stringify(arr[0].id));
```

i am getting undefined in console and i change the id with actual key name i am getting the object details.. `console.log("obj "+ JSON.stringify(arr[0].table1));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`var id = 'table1';
console.log("obj " + JSON.stringify(arr[0][id]));`

Comment: @Turbut Alin,thanks for the answer, i am trying to access the values in loop but getting undefined every time, please see the loop below, var id ="table2"; for(let i=0; i<arr.length;i++){ var tone=arr[i].id; console.log("table Dictonary:: obj for testing "+JSON.stringify(tone)); }

Comment: don't use `tone = arr[i].id`, but `tone = arr[i][id]`

Answer (score 0):

this will work  ==>

```
var id ="table1";
console.log(" obj = "+JSON.stringify(arr[0][id]));
```

or

```
console.log(" obj = "+arr[0].table1);
```

in the first example, you are treating your object as a json by stringify it & in the second we are using it as POJO.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i am trying to access the values in loop but getting undefined every time, please see the loop  below,
var id ="table2";
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
    var tone=arr[i].id;
   console.log("table Dictonary:: obj for testing "+JSON.stringify(tone));
   }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `arr[0].id`, use `arr[0][id]`.

- `arr[0].id` is equivalent to accessing the id field from the first element of the array `arr`
- `arr[0][id]` is equivalent to accessing the field `${id}` (i.e. the field which has the key, value of the `id` variable) from the first element of the array `arr`